# Qt start new application and quit

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make simple updater of my application. I wrote function which is downloading update files, and simple console application to copy update files to main application directory. I have tried to call QProcess::start and QProcess::startDetached to run updater, but updater which was launched by main application is closing when main application is closing too. Code below is executing in main.cpp:

```
if(Update::checkForUpdates()) //if there is update, download it.
{
    QProcess::startDetached(qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/updater.exe"); //process which copying update files to main directory.
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to close main application without closing processes launched by it?

Comment: you have probably some other issue with your updater - startDetached will launch process that is not related to your app process and should not be closed after your app quit. Did you check if startDetached returns true?

Comment: updater.exe is immediately closed after "return 0", if i remove this line, it's working fine. QProcess::startDetached returns true.

Comment: Does the `updater.exe` rely on any resource that the main application is owning - a socket perhaps?

Comment: No, i tried to run this way cmd.exe copied from system32 instead of updater.exe, and few other applications, that aren't connected with Qt in any way, they're always closing after return 0 line is executed. Is it a bug?

Comment: Do not return 0, use QApplication::quit instead.

Comment: QApplication::quit() works only after return qapplication.exec() - if i change return 0 to this line it won't work.

Comment: Ok, the problem was debugger .. outside it all works great with simple QProcess::startDetached("xxx");